# matlab function for sum of n number of input?

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab. This might be a silly question.
The problem says:
Write a function sum_var which takes variable number of scalar inputs & returns their sum

E.g.

```
sum_var(2,4,6)
ans =
    16
```

I tried `varargin`,`nargin` however i cant manipulate those commands to get a desired output.

Comment: Show the code that you have right now that isn't working.

Comment: How can `sum_var(2,4,6)` give `16`? What sort of magic math are you working with?

Comment: 2+4+6 = 16? Really? New math.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have a function that takes several scalar inputs and give you their sum, then do the following:

```
function  result  = sum_var(varargin)
       result = sum(cell2mat(varargin));
end
```

The problem you have is that varargin is a cell array and you have to transform it to a matrix array (using `cell2mat()`) before using the `sum()` function on it.

Comment: To make it a really nice function, you could validate the input arguments to make sure they're all numeric and scalar as they're supposed to be.